# C++ MFC Dialog - How to display items from a MySQL database in a list control?

Tags: c++, mysql, mfc, dialog, listcontrol

I am learning on C++ MFC using Visual studio 2005.

I want to get data from an Oracle MySQL database and display it in a list control. Somehow the code is working, but the display is weird and horrible, I feel that something is missing from my code.

How do I have to modify my code? There is one field in the database I don't want to display which is the UserID.

Below is the code I came up with:

```
void CPplCMain::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    unsigned short Port = 3306;
    char *IPAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    char *UserName = "root";
    char *Password = "Root";
    char *DBName = "inomatic";

    MYSQL *ssock;
    MYSQL_RES   *res;
    MYSQL_ROW   row;
    //char execsql[500];
    ssock = (MYSQL *)malloc(sizeof(MYSQL));
    //在某些版本中，不需要该初始化工作，可观看mysql.H以及readme
    mysql_init(ssock);
    if(ssock == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox("EROR: MySQL ssock init error. \n");
        return;
    }
    //MessageBox("MySQL ssock init OK. \n");

    ssock = mysql_real_connect(ssock, IPAddress, UserName, Password, NULL, Port, NULL, 0);
    if(!ssock)
    {
        MessageBox("conn fail... \n");
        mysql_errno(ssock);
    }

    if(mysql_select_db(ssock, DBName) != 0)
    {
        MessageBox("select db error. \n");
        return;
    }

    //SQL查询语句
    if(mysql_query( ssock,"SELECT countryName FROM countries"))
    {
        MessageBox("Found", mysql_error(ssock));
    }
    if( !(res = mysql_store_result(ssock)) )
    {
        MessageBox("Disconnected!", mysql_error(ssock));
    }
    while( (row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) )
    {
        for(int i=0 ; i<mysql_num_fields(res); i++)
        {
           TRACE("%s ",row[i],"\n");
           m_CountryList.AddString(row[i]);
        }
        TRACE("\n");
    }

    if(mysql_query( ssock,"SELECT * FROM shop"))
    {
        MessageBox("Shop table Found", mysql_error(ssock));
    }
    if( !(res = mysql_store_result(ssock)) )
    {
        MessageBox("Disconnected!", mysql_error(ssock));
    }
    while( (row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) )
    {
        for(int i=0 ; i<mysql_num_fields(res); i++)
        {
            TRACE("%s ",row[i],"\n");
            //m_ShopList.AddString(row[i]);
            int nIndex = m_ShopListCtrl.InsertItem(i, row[i]);
            m_ShopListCtrl.SetItemText(nIndex, i,  row[i]);
        }
        TRACE("\n");
    }

    if(mysql_query( ssock,"SELECT * FROM peoplecounter"))
    {
        MessageBox("People Counter table Found", mysql_error(ssock));
    }
    if( !(res = mysql_store_result(ssock)) )
    {
        MessageBox("Disconnected!", mysql_error(ssock));
    }
    while( (row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) )
    {
        for(int i=0 ; i<mysql_num_fields(res); i++)
        {
            TRACE("%s ",row[i], "\n");
            //m_PplCounterList.AddString(row[i]);
            int nIndex = m_PplCounterCtrl.InsertItem(i, row[i]);
            m_PplCounterCtrl.SetItemText(nIndex, i,  row[i]);
        }
        TRACE("\n");
    }

    mysql_close(ssock);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
}
```

Here is an image of my list control after filling it with data from my database:

[image: Image of my list control after filling it with data from my database]

As you can see in the image, the first row is displayed correctly, but for the next six rows duplicated data is shown row by row, before the next data set is displayed correctly in row eight.

Comment: _"the display is weird and horrible":_ You have to show us, what you actually get and what you want to get. Otherwise nobody can help you...

Comment: I can upload picture due to lack of reps. example i got 3 column of item to display testid1, testname, testaddress.

for 1st row of item it is displayed in correct order in the roll 1 testid1, testname1, testaddress1.
however when it goes to 2nd row it suppose to display other data like testid2, testname2, testaddress2. but instead it display testname1 while the 2 other column empty and row 3 testaddress1.
when it ends then the 4th row display testid2, testname2, testaddress2. and continue the same pattern.

Comment: I don't know much about MySQL, but according to the documentation on [mysql_fetch_row()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-fetch-row.html) you might need to use the function [mysql_fetch_lengths()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-fetch-lengths.html) as well.

Comment: By the way, be careful with statements like `char *UserName = "root";` because this is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (see first example).

Comment: If you still have a problem, then please upload an image to, for example, http://tinypic.com/ and post the link here. I can add the image to your post.

Comment: Here the pic of my dummy data display for the row it display correctly but when it goes to 2nd row the duplcated data is shown row by row before the next data
http://tinypic.com/r/5m0rrr/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is, that you insert a row into your list control for every column entry of a database row. You have to insert a new row into your list control only once before your `for` loop, for example, like this:

```
while(row = mysql_fetch_row(res))
{
    // Insert a new row at the end of the list control.
    // Do this only once per database row.
    int nNewIndex = m_PplCounterCtrl.GetItemCount();
    int nCurIndex = m_PplCounterCtrl.InsertItem(nNewIndex, row[0]);

    // Insert all remaining database column entries.
    // Insert them into the current row of the list control.
    for(int i = 1; i < mysql_num_fields(res); i++)
    {            
        m_PplCounterCtrl.SetItemText(nCurIndex, i, row[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! finally its solve! i figure out where i go wrong and change similar to your code but the index order instead of 0,1,2,3,4 it reverse 4,3,2,1,0. your code is perfect, solve all my errors i have change my code to use yours! once again thank you so much !^^ learning C++ MFC Dialog is hard x.X might need your help often :D

Comment: You are welcome! And learning MFC is indeed a challenge. If you run into more problems, then just post another question on SO. But please make sure that it is [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and that you give as many details as possible right from the beginning. A initially [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) has the greatest chance of receiving an answer. But you can edit your question at any time to improve it.